# How import data in Excel file to database table in angularjs and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, import

I have developed an application, and in this application I want to import user data into my table (the data must be filled in 3 table in database), I want to import data into Exel file in my table, and since i am a beginner in angularJS and .NET, i do not know how,
 my question is: how to import data in Excel file to my table in the application and thank's

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy process using angularjs.  You mention .net so I’m assuming that you’re running an mvc app with angular. If that’s the case, why not create a service in mvc using one of the libraries designed for that? I’d suggest [epplus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) as it doesn’t require the Microsoft Jet DB engine.

Comment: Hi, I work with .net web api and angularjs, and I develop a function, it works when I import the data into a table, but the problem how to import the data into 3 table in DB !!! . and the 3 tables are linked to each other